# Infinispan 12.1.1.Final missing cache configuration in the admin console (Server Management Console)

Tags: admin, infinispan, infinispan-10

we have installed Infinispan 12.1.1.Final using the official link:
https://infinispan.org/docs/dev/titles/server/server.html

After download and install of the infinispan-server-${version}.zip

The cluster (3 server nodes) is available but accessing to the admin console a lot of missing functionalities:

- Cache container configuration: it's not possibile to configure all cache parameters
- Missing cluster management (i.e. start new server)

Only available:

- Data Container: missing parameters configuration
- Global Statistics
- Cluster Membership => only visualization of the 3 nodes of the cluster
- About

Does anyone know if we need to enable some flags in the configuration or we need to install some plugins to have a complete management with all the features?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean “ it's not possibile to configure all cache parameters”?

Comment: “Start a new cache”, if you call the server.sh in the other machine. Do you see the server?

Comment: Hi @Diego, I have started 3 servers using the version infinispan-server-12.1.0.Final  and the command /bin/server.sh  ---> After that the cluster now is up & running  and shown in the web app console. In the previous version 9.4 (based on Jboss) the cache configuration parameters were visible and editable. Furthermore, again from the console, it was possible to start the cluster and execute commands on the servers. All these commands and configuration possibilities seem to be not present in version 12 on the web app console (Infinispan Server Management Console)

Comment: Hi @Diego, I don't know if there is a configuration parameter that can be used to enable all the functionalities to manage the cluster and cache configuration. Do you know if there is any parameter to enable in order to show these functionalities in the Infinispan Server Management Console? Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid the `cluster management` feature won't be implemented. You can use docker/ansible/systemd/kubernetes to do the cluster management. Container configuration is static and it is defined in the `fininispan.xml`; it is not possible to change it at runtime and, if changed, it requires a cluster restart.